# Загадочные кнопки

Tags: android, button

Всем добра! Ребят, подскажите, что за вид кнопок реализован *google'ом* в *Google Maps* приложении?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*А что в них особенного?*

**UPD:** 
Когда зажимаю он выделяет затемненным фоном в форме круга. Это Custom кнопка? или FAB без явного фона? как-то так...

Comment: А что в них особенного?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот элемент называется Bottom Bar. На него есть разные библиотеки на гитхабе.
Конкретно эта внешне похожа на [вот эту](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar) библиотеку.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/94658)

Comment: в точку! Спасибо)

Comment: @Doofy поправил, спасибо за корректировку.